# RTL multicols table of contents on beamer

Tags: beamer, multicol, bidi

I want to use Multicols for table of contents on Beamer for Arabic document, the problem that it starts from left column not right column here is my MWE:

```
    % !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multicol}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}} % framebreaks without numbering
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]% align the frametitle to the right
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\graphicspath{{pics/}}
%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic} % to change the laguage in the section and frame title to persian
% This work as: \a{متن فارسی}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for enumerate~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myenum}[1]
{
\par\vspace{3pt}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize \pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
\pgftext{\usebeamerfont*{item projected}\textcolor{white}{#1}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for itemize~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitem}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.1}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitemII}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
\setRTL \myenum{\inserttocsectionnumber}
\inserttocsection\par
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \rightskip=3ex\myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}
\begin{document}
%\selectlanguage{arabic}
\title{\textarabic{بعنوان عنوان نعنوان }}
\author{AUTHOR}
\date{\today}
\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{
\frametitle{\textarabic{فهرست مطالب}}
\begin{minipage}{1.\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{multicols}{2} 
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\frame{
\frametitle{\textarabic{سیستمهای فرمیونی همبسته:مایع}}
\begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{itemize}[label=\protect\myitemII, rightmargin=0mm]
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\end{itemize}           
\ar{متن فارسی .....}            
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: inverted culumns]

Comment: Have you considered the `bidipresentation` class?

Comment: I tried it before, but Xepersian package use Persian as a main language, i want this for Arabic.

Comment: The example file for `bidipresentation` uses `xepersian`, but you can substitute `arabxetex` and adjust the commands for selecting fonts accordingly (e.g., `\documentclass{bidipresentation}` `\usepackage{arabxetex}` `\setmainfont{Amiri}` `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}`).

Comment: The columns are arranged as you wish if you make Arabic the main language and English the “other” language.

Comment: Thank you, but i have a long presentation with several features and specific thinks that fit my needs, Using arabic as a main language causes other problems such as headline and footline in Madrid theme ...

Comment: multicol supports column reordering, maybe you have to explicitly ask for that in your scenario, e.g. \RLmulticolcolumns

Comment: @Frank Mittelbach this solution does not work in this case, thank you.

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour I can't see why, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind to manually specify the breaking point, you could do:

```
    % !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multicol}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}} % framebreaks without numbering
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]% align the frametitle to the right
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\graphicspath{{pics/}}
%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic} % to change the laguage in the section and frame title to persian
% This work as: \a{متن فارسی}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for enumerate~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myenum}[1]
{
\par\vspace{3pt}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize \pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
\pgftext{\usebeamerfont*{item projected}\textcolor{white}{#1}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for itemize~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitem}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.1}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitemII}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
\setRTL \myenum{\inserttocsectionnumber}
\inserttocsection\par
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \rightskip=3ex\myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\textarabic{فهرست مطالب}}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{Arabic}
            \flushright
            \tableofcontents[sections=5-]
        \end{Arabic}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{Arabic}
            \flushright
            \tableofcontents[sections=-4]
        \end{Arabic}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Despite the claim in the comment that `\RLmulticolcolumns` doesn't work it does (at least I can't see where it fails, or why it could). All you have to do is to add it to the frame with the table of contents, e.g.,

```
\frame{
\frametitle{\textarabic{فهرست مطالب}}
\begin{minipage}{1.\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\RLmulticolcolumns    % <--- here to act only in this frame
\begin{multicols}{2} 
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
}
```

We then get the following output:

[image]

and here is the full code I used as requested (with TL 2017) to get the above output, but really it is simply the original example with the single line added:

```
    % !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multicol}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}} % framebreaks without numbering
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]% align the frametitle to the right
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\graphicspath{{pics/}}
%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic} % to change the laguage in the section and frame title to persian
% This work as: \a{متن فارسی}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for enumerate~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myenum}[1]
{
\par\vspace{3pt}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize \pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
\pgftext{\usebeamerfont*{item projected}\textcolor{white}{#1}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for itemize~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitem}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.1}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitemII}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
\setRTL \myenum{\inserttocsectionnumber}
\inserttocsection\par
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \rightskip=3ex\myitem
\inserttocsubsection\par%
}
\begin{document}
%\selectlanguage{arabic}
\title{\textarabic{بعنوان عنوان نعنوان }}
\author{AUTHOR}
\date{\today}
\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{
\frametitle{\textarabic{فهرست مطالب}}
\begin{minipage}{1.\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\RLmulticolcolumns
\begin{multicols}{2} 
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}
\subsubsection{Title}
\frame{
\frametitle{\textarabic{سیستمهای فرمیونی همبسته:مایع}}
\begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{itemize}[label=\protect\myitemII, rightmargin=0mm]
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\item
\ar{متن فارسی .....}
\end{itemize}           
\ar{متن فارسی .....}            
\end{Arabic}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your answer seems to be very interesting, please post a complete MWE, i tried your short answer but did not work.

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour not sure what you want. Take your example file as it is in the question add this single line in the place shown and it comes out correctly (with TeX Live 2017 distribution) that is with multicol Package: `multicol 2017/04/11 v1.8q multicolumn formatting (FMi)`.  By the way MWE stands for minimal working example your example above is by no means really minimal :-). What exactly does not "work"?

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour have you been able to use it successfully? If not, can you make a MWE showing where it fails for you?